# R omits repeat values from my excel data

Tags: r, excel

So I've imported my data from excel as

```
Name <- read.csv("C:\\.......csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

and named a column of the excel file as a list in R as

Name of `list <- c(unique(Name$NameofColumn))`
which has worked for me numerous times before, except now, R is only reading new values, and completely ignoring repeat values. 
For example, if my excel column was: 3, 4, 3, 5, 
R reads it as 3, 4, 5

Comment: What is the purpose of the `unique()` in there? One way to describe what `unique` does would be "omit repeat values", so if you don't want to do that, maybe leave out the `unique()` part... at which point your `c()` probably isn't doing anything either, so you could just do `result = Name$NameofColumn` if all you want to do is pull out a single column.

Comment: If you need more help than that, I'd encourage you to make a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), with a few lines of a CSV file and some R code that runs on it.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to look deeper at your terminology so that you understand better (and can describe better) what is going on. Excel can export data and save it as a CSV, but CSV format is a very simple text file (*CSV:* comma separated values), whereas an Excel file is much more complicated. It's good to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gregor mentioned, if you simply need to extract one of the columns as a list, then running
`Name_of_list <- Name$NameofColumn`
would yield the desired result. unique() will only return unique values of from the column